# Heap corruption on dynamic programming problem

Tags: c++, heap-corruption

I'm getting an heap corruption error and I can't figure out where it is.

The problem is a coin change problem using dynamic programming. C is the array with the coin values, n is the size of the array, T is the target change, usedCoins is an array where the number of used coins should be mapped (i.e if C[1] = 2 and 3 2-coins are used, usedCoins[2] = 2 with all other indexes to 0.

Here's the code:

```
bool changeMakingUnlimitedDP(unsigned int C[], unsigned int n, unsigned int T, unsigned int usedCoins[]) {

static auto minCoins = new unsigned int[T+1]{UINT_MAX};
minCoins[0] = 0;
static auto lastCoin = new unsigned int[T+1]{0};

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    usedCoins[i] = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j <= T; j++){
        if(j >= C[i]){
            minCoins[j-C[i]] == 0? minCoins[j] = 1 : minCoins[j] = std::min(1 + minCoins[j - C[i]], minCoins[j-C[i]]);
            lastCoin[j] = i;
        }
    }
}

while(T > 0){
    unsigned int last = lastCoin[T];
    if(last == UINT_MAX || last < 0) return false;
    usedCoins[last]++;
    T -= C[last];
}

free(minCoins);
free(lastCoin);

return true;
```

}

When running on debug mode it goes through.

Comment: Fyi, do not `free` things that were `new`'d. Also, those are initialized as static, meaning the only get hit once, so even if you fix your `free` with `delete[]` as they should be, it is still a recipe for disaster, since the next invoke will have two dangling pointers and no place to go with them.

Comment: If you feel the obligation to give a short description of what each variable means because the name you've chosen is so uncommunicative, consider just actually naming them `coinValues`, `coinValuesSize`, `targetChange`, etc. instead

Comment: @NathanPierson it's a class problem, I didn't name anything. Please refrain from answering if you're not contributing to solving the problem. Although I appreciate the need to share proper practices, changing variable names doesn't help in any way to solve the heap corruption. Thank you in advance

Comment: @WhozCraig I added the free's because I figured the heap corruption was happening because they weren't being freed. The problem persisted before (and after) removing them

EDIT: just realized the static isn't doing anything there since the method isn't recursive, and it was the responsible for the heap corruption. Thanks man!

Comment: Also,  your erroneous call to `free()` happens *every single time* you run through the function, whereas the `new` only happens once (because it is set into a static variable).  So even if that were a proper call to `delete[]`, it would still be a crash waiting to happen.

Comment: ***I figured the heap corruption was happening because they weren't being freed.*** A memory leak should never cause heap corruption. In this case the static makes the allocation happen only the first time you call this function. You don't want to free it because the next time you execute the code the pointer will point to memory that was already freed. The new would not happen the second time the function executes.

Comment: static could have caused the corruption for a different reason. If `T` ever got larger during the total execution of the program you would have exceeded the bounds of the allocated array because the array was allocated with whatever size `T` was when you first executed this function.

Comment: @drescherjm it was the static. I poorly understood the concept. Thanks for clearing it up!

Comment: @PedroBarbeira `static auto minCoins = new unsigned int[T+1]{UINT_MAX};` --> `std::vector<unsigned int> minCoins(T+1, UINT_MAX);` -- Once you do that, then remove those erroneous calls to `free()`, and no need to issue `delete []` calls.  The same thing with the other line of code with `static`.

Comment: @PedroBarbeira *changing variable names doesn't help in any way to solve the heap corruption* -- Please note that the comment section is for comments, not answers.  The comment concerning the renaming of variables can indeed help in debugging the code.  One-letter variable names are harder to follow, easier to get wrong (what if there is another `C` variable shadowing the upper `C` variable?), etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie this one is supposed to be done with arrays. but thanks for the attempt

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes indeed. still not relevant to the matter at hands. you could've went right away with the answer you gave above that last comment - even though said answer doesn't apply to the problem at hand. Condescending gatekeeping is the cancer of the coding community. Specially if done covertly. Hopefully I'm mistaken - miscommunication happens. Have a great one!